# what is the best way to create route for all static pages in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

I am starting in angular
And I have a problem to creating a route for my little project

I get the names for the menu pages as json

"home '' services' 'contact' etc.

And I have a ready template to display the menu properly

But I want to create a route for all pages

That looks something like this:

localhost / website / services

etc.

I want that my route gets one word after localhost / website / and return template and send a request to the server with the name of the page to get json content

In other words, I want to create a route he knew to get only the first parameter in url

how do I do it ?

Comment: You create routes with `.when()`. It looks like you want a redirect? Use `.otherwise({ controller: 'redirectController' })` (no need for a template here).

Comment: So how do I do `.when()`  where he gets a variable parameter? It is not a permanent page. with name that i know

Comment: [Check out this example](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07#the-app-module). Instead of using `redirectTo`, use `controller: 'yourController`. Within `yourController`, take care of the logic that will redirect to the correct route.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `$states`:

```
myApp
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider
        .otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('myState', {
            url: '/:requestedService'
        });
```

Now, define a controller:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {

    // Whenever state change like: "http://localhost/home", "http://localhost/contact"
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
        if (toState.name == "myState") {
            $http({
                url: "/my-url",
                data: {serviceName: toParams.requestedService}
            }).then(function(data) {
                // your json data in "data"
            });
        }
    });
});
```